# If we have three logical inputs A, B, C generating: (A'B+AC) and (AB+A'C), is there any way we can generate A from the two output?

Tags: boolean, logical-operators, xor, boolean-algebra

So we have three inputs A, B, C generating the following:
output1: A'B + AC
and 
output2: AB + A'C

Can we, using some logical gates obtain the input A from the two outputs?

Comment: @user2864740, imagine that both `o1` and `o2` are `1`. Now what can you say about `A`? Nothing. All you can say is that both `B` and `C` are `1`.

Comment: Actually, the author has two 2-1 MUXes with the same selector, but swapped outputs.